# How can I get a table to auto scroll (y) if necessary with a dynamic height?

Tags: html, css

Essentially I want a table to show as much as will fit in your browser window.  But instead of scrolling the whole page down, I need only the tbody to scroll.  Can you help?

Here's a fiddle to help: http://jsfiddle.net/drKpT/

And my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"><h1>This is my header</h1></div>
    <div id="sidebar"><ul><li>Nav 1</li><li>Nav 2</li></ul></div><div id="content">
        <div id="title"><h2>This is my content title</h2></div>
        <div id="data">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>Pssssssst... &nbsp; &nbsp; I'd like this area (tbody) to scroll if it's taller than the window you're in</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"><p>This is my footer</p></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
div,ul,li,h1,h2,td,tr {
    padding:0;margin:0;
}
#container {
    width:100%;
    background:#efefef;
}
#header {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#dedede;
}
#sidebar {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
    background:#cdcdcd;
}
#content {
    display:inline-block;
    width:80%;
    background:#bcbcbc;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;
    width:100%;
}
tbody {
    border:3px dashed;
    width:100%;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    background:#ababab;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the size of the tbody as it's expanded with the content height. To answer to this solution you need to create another table. So you have one table that contain only the thead. The other table which is put under contain only tbody, wrapped inside a div with overflow auto and some height

If you want your table to to fill as much free space as possible, here is the pseudo-code logic:

`wanted_height = window_height - header_height - footer_height - some_fix_constant`

EDIT: 3rd version, http://jsfiddle.net/drKpT/3/

Comment: Yes, I tried this first, but my td's are auto width and don't match up when I split up the table.

Comment: And you can't set manually the size of the first column? I think I get what you mean. The header width should be a little smaller

Comment: @Ryan Check the 3rd version

Answer (score 0):

you could use it like :

```
tbody {
    border:3px dashed;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `overflow` css property.  It allows you to define what happens to content that is larger than the containing object.  If you always want show scroll bars, even if not possible, you can use `overflow: scroll;`.  If you only want to see scroll bars when the container is scrollable, use `overflow: auto;`.  `overflow: auto` is the most common setting.

```
tbody{
overflow: auto;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
}
```